# Change Parent div Height depending on child absolute div height using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Iam working on project where I cam across the situation like this.

I need my parent div stretch its height depending on the child div. The parent height is fixed for 400px;

```
#parent-div{
min-height:400px;
width:250px;
background-color:#333;
position:relative;
}


#child-div{
position:absolute;
height:auto;
top: 0%;
```

}

I need my child div to be `absolute` positioned.

The child div consists of table contents where the height may increase depending on the contents. I need my parent div stretch accordingly. So i need a asolution where the rendered height of child is calculated and make the parent div stretch extra than child.

```
If rendered height of child div is 400px, I need my parent div to be 450px;
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Show us what you've tried show we can help you solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to set the width of the parent div to 100%

```
#parent-div{
min-height:400px;
width:250px;             <-
background-color:#333;
position:relative;
}
```

To

```
#parent-div{
min-height:400px;
width:100%;
background-color:#333;
position:relative;
}
```

Hope that helps you!

Comment: I tried this, it did not work. So i am looking for js solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add this javascript since you are using jquery:

```
$().ready(function(){
    ch = $('#child-div').height();
    $('#parent-div').css({
        height : ch + 50 + 'px'
    })
});
```

Demo : **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLwmb/)**

Comment: This actually works fine. Should I leave this $().ready(function()as it is or should I add something like $( document ).ready(function()?

Comment: doesnt work for me. i added console.log(ch); in there which echos out "0" no matter jow many js solutions i try they all have this same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var parent= $('#parent');
    var parentOffset = parent.offset();
    var bottom = 0; 
    parent.find('*').each(function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        var elemOffset = elem.offset();
        var elemBottom = elemOffset.top + elem.outerHeight(true) - parentOffset.top;
        if (elemBottom > bottom) {
            bottom = elemBottom;
        }
    });

    parent.css('min-height', bottom);

});
```