# Change Parent div Height depending on child absolute div height & top positioning using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is an additional question regarding the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016509/change-parent-div-height-depending-on-child-absolute-div-height-using-javascript) (before the top positioning broke it) found at the bottom.

My problem is that once the css property `top` is used, the div is then offset and bleeds out of the wrapping parent div.

```js
$().ready(function(){
    ch = $('#child-div').height();
    $('#parent-div').css({
        height : ch + 50 + 'px'
    })
});
```

```css
#parent-div{
    min-height: 400px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;
}


#child-div{
    background-color: red;
    opacity: .8;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent-div'>
    <div id='child-div'>
        <div id="child2">
            Test 2<br />
            Test 2<br />
            Test 2<br />
            Test 2<br />
            Test 2<br />
        </div>
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
        test <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time and then your question makes no sense to those who come across it. Just include your code in a "code snippet", right here in your question. This also makes it easier for us to copy that code and provide you with a working solution.

Comment: Well then instead of 50, add the actual 200 to the height you are setting ...?

Comment: @CBroe Forgot to mention that the div can increase in a variant of sizes due to dynamic content loading within the child div (a form with a variable number of options that can change weekly) So I need the parent div to be able to change based on the total height of the dynamic content within the child div. (This is such a ridiculous issue...but I'm using Instapage API which is so limited )

Comment: @ScottMarcus This is my first time posting, I wasn't aware I could post the working code in here, that's awesome. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Then you will either have to set something up that adjusts the height when necessary (by hooking into whatever changes the content to begin with, a mutation observer, or an interval), or not absolute position he child.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `50` isn't enough if the child element has a `top` of `200`.

Also, in JavaScript, any expression that contains:

```
"someString" + someNumber
```

will cause the number to be converted to a string and the result will be the concatenated string. If the only operator in the expression is `+` (as it is in your case, the expression will be evaluated left to right and, in your case, that's OK, but it does open up your code to potential bugs down the line.

It's better to organize the expression so that the math gets done first and then concatenate the `"px"`.

```js
$(function(){
    ch = $('#child-div').height();
    $('#parent-div').css({
        // Do the math first, then concatenate
        height: (ch + 200) + 'px'
    });
});
```

```css
#parent-div{
  min-height:400px;
  width:250px;
  background-color:yellow;
  position:relative;

}

#child-div{
  background-color:red;
  opacity: .8;
  position:absolute;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent-div'>
    <div id='child-div'>
      <div id="child2">
        Test 2<br>
        Test 2<br>
        Test 2<br>
        Test 2<br>
        Test 2<br>
      </div>
        test <br>
        test <br>
        test <br>
        test <br>
        test <br>
        test <br>
        test <br>
        test <br>
        test <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add an extra 200 to your height in JQuery to offset..

```
$().ready(function(){
    ch = $('#child-div').height();
    $('#parent-div').css({
        height : ch + 250 + 'px'
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Read my response to the answer provided above. I was missing a few important details.